# Installing php5-intl

Tags: php, ubuntu, orocrm

I'm currently trying to install OroCRM onto a linux VirtualBox system to try it out. However when trying to composer install, it gives me certain errors. A few of them require ext-intl, after searching everyone says just do:

sudo apt-get install php5-intl

However this does not work and gives me this message:

Package php5-intl is not available, but reffered to by other packages.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source.
E: Package php5-intl has no installation candidate.

Does anyone know how to properly install php5-intl or ext-intl? I've tried update before installing and various other solutions found on the web.

Comment: I had this recently, I had to completely reinstall PHP and redownload the latest intl file from the website and then it worked.

Comment: https://pecl.php.net/package/intl

Comment: What do i do with the TGZ file on linux?

Comment: It's an archive file, open it up/extract it and take the required php intl file.